# Change date format Nov 18, 2014 to 2014-11-18

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I am trying to change the format of a date but cannot get it to work from Nov 18, 2014 to 2014-11-18

```
String s="Nov 18, 2014"
s= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new SimpleDateFormat("LLL dd, yyyy").parse(s));
```

something is wrong with this part

```
new SimpleDateFormat("LLL dd, yyyy").parse(s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `LLL` to `MMM` and it should work. `LLL` is not defined (corrent value). You should look at

- [Class SimpleDateFormat at official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
- [Common Pattern Strings for java.text.SimpleDateFormat](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/simpledateformat.htm)

As **@Reimeus** pointed out `LLL` keyword should work but for Android platform. Here are [official docs.](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 3):

Your default `Locale` may not match the month field in the input `String`. Try

```
new SimpleDateFormat("LLL dd, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
```

Answer (score 2):

[it is **not** `LLL`, it is `MMM`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Change it to

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy", Locale.US).parse(s));
```

Comment: @Reimeus Reimeus - question is not pointed to Android. I also didn't know that fact and i dont like it. It's a little confusing at least for me :)

Answer (score 0):

`new SimpleDateFormat("LLL dd, yyyy").parse(s)` should be changed to `new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy").parse(s)`

Answer (score 0):

[It seems like](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) `LLL` doesn't exist ; if you want the format for months, it's `MMM` instead.