# Difference between MMM and LLL (Stand alone value) in SimpleDateFormat object

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

I am trying to find out what the difference between three Ls (LLL) and three Ms (MMM) in the declaration of a SimpleDateFormat object ( i.e. new SimpleDateFormat("MMM/LLL dd, yyyy") ). I have searched the web and the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), but the only thing I could find is that the one is used for stand-alone cases and the other for context-sensitive ones. Can anyone help me on what's the difference between those formats? Thanks!

Comment: that question has already been answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27159646/change-date-format-nov-18-2014-to-2014-11-18

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The DateFormatSymbols contains context sensitive form of month, we need
standalone form. This difference is not apparent in English but makes a
difference in other languages such as Russian, Slovak where the standard or standalone form is distinguishable from the locale.

Example and explanation for russian locale:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/25329549/1164913