# What is a difference between TextStyle.FULL and TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE

Tags: java, date, localization, java-time, date-formatting

The `java.time.format.TextStyle` enum has the following options:

```
/**
 * Full text, typically the full description.
 * For example, day-of-week Monday might output "Monday".
 */
FULL(Calendar.LONG_FORMAT, 0),
/**
 * Full text for stand-alone use, typically the full description.
 * For example, day-of-week Monday might output "Monday".
 */
FULL_STANDALONE(Calendar.LONG_STANDALONE, 0),
```

My question is: what is a difference between `FULL` and `FULL_STANDALONE` - what does "for stand-alone" use mean?

Comment: Not knowing the full story, in some languages the *genitive* form of a month name is used with day of month, a bit like when in English we say *22 of March* sometimes. If you are mentioning the month without day of month, you don’t want to say *of March* but just *March*, which in such languages you do by using the *nominative* form of the month name instead. So `FULL_STANDALONE` gives you the nominative while `FULL` gives you the genitive.

Comment: There’s some information here: https://cldr.unicode.org/translation/date-time/date-time-patterns Scroll down to **When to use Standalone vs. Formatting**. Also a related question here: [Difference between MMM and LLL (Stand alone value) in SimpleDateFormat object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45398202/difference-between-mmm-and-lll-stand-alone-value-in-simpledateformat-object) (while no one should use `SimpleDateFormat` anymore, the answer is valid to java.time too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In English, there is no difference between standard and standalone versions.

The [Android documentation for TextStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/format/TextStyle) has a little more information than its Oracle JavaDoc counterpart.

> However, in other languages there is a difference in the word used when the text is used alone, as opposed to in a complete date. For example, the word used for a month when used alone in a date picker is different to the word used for month in association with a day and year in a date